# Hide hour (if no need) in gmdate() function PHP

Tags: php, datetime

is there any way to hide hour in `gmdate` function?

I mean,  I want to show xx.xx.xx if seconds>3600 else xx:xx. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question, but I do not believe this is possible with the standard functionality of `gmdate`. You'll have to perform your own conditional. Here's a simple example:

```
$time = time();
$date_info = getdate( $time);
$format = ( $date_info['minutes'] > 1) ? 'h.i.s' : 'i.s';
echo gmdate( $format, $time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find in documentation short answer so I think this method could help:

```
public function getTime($time)
{
    $format = 's';
    if ($time >= 3600) {
        $format = 'H:i:s';
    } elseif ($time >= 60) {
        $format = 'i:s';
    }
    return trim(gmdate($format, $time), 0);
}
```

Comment: That's not a method

Comment: yep, sorry, now it's the method